# Any JavaScript Library that makes CSS3/HTML5 website work on all browsers, including IE6-8?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

Is there any JavaScript Library that makes `CSS3/HTML5` website fully work on all browsers, including IE6-8?

Latest [`eCSStener`](http://ecsstender.org/) and [`Modernizr`](http://www.modernizr.com/) does not make `CSS3` work on `IE6-8`.

Answer (score 3):

No.

CSS 3 and HTML 5 (neither of which is even finished yet) make some things that are possible easier and some things that are impossible possible.

You've already found libraries to simulate the bits that make the possible easier, but you aren't going to make the impossible possible using a JavaScript library. HTML 4 / DOM 1/2/3 / CSS 2.1 simply don't provide methods to store [large amounts of data between sessions](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/), [run background processes](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), and a host of other things.

Some things could be simulated, but not without side effects. For example, you could duplicate text and use positioning to fake `text-shadow`, but then screenreaders would read out the content twice.

You need to think very carefully about what new technologies you want, and build your pages according to the principles of progressive enhancement.

Answer (score 2):

There's [HTML5 Now](http://code.google.com/p/html5-now/), though it's not seen much activity recently and probably isn't ready for production use.  It's by the same guy who wrote the [IE7.js library](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

For now you're probably better off limiting the amount of CSS3 and HTML5 you use and then looking for specific ways of enabling cross browser support for those bits.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the problem with rendering HTML5 elements such as `<header>`, just add a simple javascript hack to the `<head>` of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.createElement('header');
    document.createElement('article');
    // ...and so on
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for JavaScript Library that makes CSS3/HTML5 featured website fully work on all browsers.