# Are there any JavaScript 'packs' that can make CSS3 compatible on IE browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, css

I was wondering if there are any packages available out there to make CSS3 capabilities available to browsers that do not support it yet.

The way I envision this, and I've been unable to find anything via search, is the JS would detect the browser and load its own library that essentially do the CSS3 functions using JavaScript.

I know there is a JS library to make PNG files work property on older IE browsers, I was wondering if anybody's been working on something to allow other things to work as well.

This would allow developers to utilize CSS3 in their web applications, and let the JS handle the comparability.  I'd be willing to pay for something like this.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any JavaScript Library that makes CSS3/HTML5 website work on all browsers, including IE6-8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180579/any-javascript-library-that-makes-css3-html5-website-work-on-all-browsers-includ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently came across a rather elegant new solution for CSS3 in IE. I think it's pretty close to what you want: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Awesome, that looks exactly like what I was looking for, will have to test out.

Comment: Just make sure to read the "Known Issues" page. It has a bunch of really important info about using it.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I have found to doing this is Dean Edwards' IE scripts.  I don't think it fully supports all CSS3 features yet (as most of CSS3 is still in the works and hasn't been solidified), but what it will do, is allow you to use all common CSS selectors that normally don't work in earlier versions of IE.  It really helps to make IE a more standards compliant browser and avoid the use of CSS hacks and/or multiple stylesheets.  I've been looking for anything about CSS3 support in his script and haven't found anything yet.  Like I said, it mostly allows the use of all the selectors, plus it does have a PNG fix built into it.  Bonus!

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Answer (score 0):

For your info, there's also such a pack to do stuff from allowing :hover in other stuff than anchors, there's also stuff to fix IE's screw-ups of the DOM etc.

But I don't think there's a definitive list/pack to do what you want.

If there was, it would have taken on the internet like a storm ;).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such a library yet. It would be alot of work, and most are satisfied with graceful degradation in old browsers rather than trying to implement the missing features in javascript. However, there is a library that does the first half: feature detection. It's call modernizr: http://www.modernizr.com/